# How can return all instances of duplicate text values in a referenced position

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, duplicates, vlookup

I have hundreds of rows of data with dates in the first column and sites in text with decimals in subsequent columns. Each site has a 6 letter name and distinguished by the group it belongs to by the first 3 letters.  There are two groups, coy and rac. I need to find all of the groups in each row which share the exact same combination of the last three letters of the site name.

For example, in the row

```
          a               b                  c               d                     e                 f  
1 8/29/2012 CoyBGA 0.0201041667  CoyVCC 0.46437  RacBGA 2.38541667   RacBGA 5.084490740    RacBGD 4.36805
```

I would like to add another cell in the next column g which shows all instances of duplicates of the last 3 letters, like below

```
CoyBGA 0.0201041667  RacBGA 2.38541667   RacBGA 5.084490740
```

---

```
=(VLOOKUP(("*"&(RIGHT(B1:F1,3))),B1:F1,1,FALSE))
```

only returns CoyBGA, but I need it to list all results. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: In your example, do you want all three matches in the same cell?  What if there is more than one set of duplicates?  Also, will there always be six columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use `FILTERXML`

```
=TEXTJOIN("  ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><a>"&TEXTJOIN("</a><a>",TRUE,B1:F1)&"</a></t>","//a[contains(.,'BGA')]"))
```

If you have a version of Excel that includes the new Dynamic Array function `FILTER`, you can do that like this

```
=TEXTJOIN("  ",TRUE,FILTER(TRANSPOSE(B1:F1),TRANSPOSE(MID(B1:F1,4,SEARCH(" ",B1:F1)-4))="BGA"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I am actually looking for something that represents the last 3 letters, not exact text BGA as there are a lot of values. That's why I originally tried RIGHT(B1:F1,3). So the extracted values in g would be all instances of duplicate values, such as CoyBGA and RacBGA. Is there a way to do this instead?

Comment: These formula produce _exactly_ what you provided as the required result from the sample data in you Q.  If that's not what you want, please edit your Q to clarify

Comment: It does not work for this row.   7/20/2012 racAPC 0.223310185185185 racCHA 1.54398148148148E-02 racCHC 0.940648148148148 racPBA 0.89212962962963 racPBE 0.106064814814815 racRIVB 0.972048611111111 racVCH 0.186111111111111 CoyPBE 0.127430555555556 CoyPBA 0.967314814814815 CoyPBE 0.208541666666667                                            
There are hundreds of rows, so I cannot change 'BGA' to the right text each time.